javascript function looping array
Why can't I get the output I want, I tried various ways but it doesn't work, where is it wrong?
Give me a clue so I can learn.
let laptop = ["asus", "lenovo", "acer", "hp", "axioo"];
let gpu = [4070, 4090, 4050, 4080, 4060];

const laptopGpu  = (device, gra) => {
  device = laptop.sort()
  gra = gpu.sort()
  let data = ""
  for(let i = 1; i < device.length; i++) {
    data = `{${device[i]} with gpu ${gra[i]}}`
  }
  return new Array (data)
}
console.log(laptopGpu(laptop,gpu));

This is the output I want:
[ 
  '{acer with gpu 4050}',
  '{asus with gpu 4060}',
  '{axioo with gpu 4070}', 
  '{hp with gpu 4080}',
  '{lenovo with gpu 4090}'
]


You are almost there. You want an array of strings as an output, but your data variable is a single string.
What you need to do is to initialize data as an empty array and push the strings to it in the loop, instead of overwriting data at each iteration

You have some errors:

Don't mutate arguments passed, so use rather toSorted() (sort() mutates an array)
Don't use the global gpu and laptop since they are passed as arguments
JS arrays starts with 0 so for(let i = 0...
Your output is an array so data should be an array and use push() to the array:



let laptop = ["asus", "lenovo", "acer", "hp", "axioo"];
let gpu = [4070, 4090, 4050, 4080, 4060];

 
const laptopGpu  = (device, gra) => {
    device = device.toSorted()
    gra = gra.toSorted()

    let data = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
       data.push(`{${device[i]} with gpu ${gra[i]}}`);
    }

    return data;
}

console.log(laptopGpu(laptop,gpu));




Why pass in laptop and gpu? With the above you can omit having args for the laptopGpu

@Petros because that’s how the code of the OP is structured (and it might be just a simplified example). And in general you want to avoid that anything in a function depends on global data (expect for values that are clearly constants).

yes but it is not using the device initial value! The solution above though it does depend on global data! See device = laptop.toSorted()

@Petros I didn‘t write the answer. But I agree that laptop.toSorted() should actually be device.toSorted()

@Petros missed that the global laptop was used also, fixed

As you have created a data variable and then assigning it a value inside for loop so everytime the loop runs it overrides the last value. Instead create an array and push the values in that array.


let laptop = ["asus", "lenovo", "acer", "hp", "axioo"];
let gpu = [4070, 4090, 4050, 4080, 4060];

 
const laptopGpu  = (device, gra) => {
    device = laptop.sort()
    gra = gpu.sort()

    let data = []

    for(let i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
       data.push(`{${device[i]} with gpu ${gra[i]}}`)
    }

    return data
}

console.log(laptopGpu(laptop, gpu));




There are some issues to the above snippet.

First of all you are passing in the arguments but you are using the
class variables. So if you intent to use the class variables there is no need to have arguments.

Secondly you treat data as a string thus it was assigning only the result of the last iteration.

Third, you where starting your loop from position 1 thus first occurrences of both arrays are skipped.


Have a look at the below. Hope it helps you understand what the problems were


let laptop = ["asus", "lenovo", "acer", "hp", "axioo"];
let gpu = [4070, 4090, 4050, 4080, 4060];

 
const laptopGpu  = (device, gra) => {
    device = device.sort()
    gra = gra.sort()

    let data = []

    for(let i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
       data.push( `{${device[i]} with gpu ${gra[i]}}`)
    }

    return data
}

console.log(laptopGpu(laptop,gpu));




You can also use Array#map as follows:


let laptop = ["asus", "lenovo", "acer", "hp", "axioo"];
let gpu = [4070, 4090, 4050, 4080, 4060];

 
const laptopGpu  = (device, gra) => {
    const g = gra.toSorted();
    const data = device.toSorted().map(
        (d,i) => `{${d} with gpu ${g[i]}}`
    );

    return data;
}

console.log(laptopGpu(laptop,gpu));




I have update my answer to a more helpfull solution
let laptops = ["asus", "lenovo", "acer", "hp", "axioo"];
let gpus = [4070, 4090, 4050, 4080, 4060];

class Laptop{
    #laptop;
  #gpu;
  
    constructor(laptop, gpu){
  this.#laptop = laptop;
  this.#gpu = gpu;
  }
  
   toString() {
    return `{${this.#laptop} with gpu ${this.#gpu}}`;
  }
  
}

const laptopGpu  = (device, gra) => {
  device = laptops.sort()
  gra = gpus.sort()

  return device.map((laptop, index) => new Laptop(laptop, gra[index]) );
}

laptopGpu(laptops, gpus).forEach(laptop => console.log(laptop.toString()));

In this example I store each laptop as an object and overwrite the toString() method.
Hope this helps.

First of all the result should be an array and not one string. And as the OP has problems with achieving it an answer that more ore less just says to do it correctly might not be helpful. You should instead include code that shows how to solve the problem.
